# Python main() multi-threading

Tags: python, multithreading, program-entry-point

I have a main.py where inside the main() I am doing 2 things that take some time to load up, but they need to be done before I can run by program. How do I run the 2 necessary things at the same time to increase the start up speed?

```
def main():


   clf_path = os.path.join(script_dir,'classifier_v1.pickle')  ### 1st thing
   f = open(clf_path, 'rb')
   print 'Loading Classifier....'
   classifier = pickle.load(f)
   f.close()

   tmp_data = api_call()   ### 2nd thing
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to comment due to 50 reputations limitation.

Python's interpreted code is single threaded due to [Global Interpreter Lock (GIL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock), so your multi-threaded code will be run as single threaded.

Using `multiprocessing` module could help to work around this issue since your code will not be affected by GIL.

You can write your 1st and 2nd thing as functions and use something similar to below

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = multiprocessing.Process(name='first', target=first_function)
    s = multiprocessing.Process(name='second', target=second_function)

    f.start()
    s.start()

    f.join()
    s.join()
```

`join` is used here to wait till processes finish their work and exit.

Please remember to start your processes first then join them in another loop to not to have them running sequentially.